Why do we always need to specify the Solidity version while coding the smart contract?
New to solidity and smart contracts. I'm unsure why do we need to be very specific (eg: pragma solidity 0.8.19;) while entering the Solidity version while designing the smart contract?
Why can't we use something like pragma solidity ^0.8.18; etc as that will generally cover all the future versions of Solidity?
Also, some learning resources to understand the theory behind this will be really appreciated.

You need to be specific with the version (pragma solidity 0.8.19) due to potential breaking changes or unexpected behavior introduced in future releases. Using a (^) like pragma solidity ^0.8.18, tells the compiler to accept any version from 0.8.18 up to, but not including, 0.9.0 and above.
I think the best way to learn more about this is to check out their doc only: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.19/
or
https://cryptozombies.io/
I hope this answer helped you!

Let's imagine you've got some code targetting version 0.7.x and you've upgraded to version 0.8.x, and not pinned the version exactly.
You might be unpleasantly surprised to discover that the value of 3**4**5 has changed from (3**4)**5 [3.4 million] in version 0.7 to 3**(4**5) [3.7e489] in version 0.8; this might lead to significant financial harm.
From the changelog:

Parser: Exponentiation is right associative. a**b**c is parsed as a**(b**c).

As a part of upgrading the version number of the code, you must verify that the code works as intended against the new version of Solidity.

Specifying a Solidity version in smart contracts helps maintain compatibility, security, and predictable behavior across the Ethereum network.
Each Solidity version may optimize code differently and improvements are typically made with each release.
Specifying a range(e.g. ^0.8.0) allows for compatibility with all future versions up to (but not including) 0.9.0, which can be helpful if minor updates include optimizations or security improvements. It also means your contract might compile with a newer version where behavior or optimizations could differ from your tested version.
https://blog.solidityscan.com/understanding-solidity-pragma-and-its-security-practices-3b5458763a34
This article may be helpful for you.
Thanks
